# How do you get arguments of correct type in Google Actions SDK?

Tags: actions-on-google, google-assistant-sdk

Google's action api seems to find the right pattern in my intent and bind to the right type, but does not return the parsed type data. For example, if I have the intent defined below in my actions.json file:

```
   {
     "description": "",
      "initialTrigger": {
        "intent": "RepeatIntent",
        "queryPatterns": [
          {
            "queryPattern": "say $SchemaOrg_Number:mynumber"
          },
          {
            "queryPattern": "say $SchemaOrg_Date:mydate"
          },
          {
            "queryPattern": "say $SchemaOrg_Time:mytime"
          }
        ]
      },
      "httpExecution": {
        "url": "https://myurl/repeat"
      }
    }
```

and I enter, "**at my action say tomorrow**" into the simulator, I receive the following arguments:

```
"arguments": [
    {
        "name": "mydate",
        "raw_text": "tomorrow",
        "text_value": "tomorrow"
    },
    {
        "name": "trigger_query",
        "raw_text": "say tomorrow",
        "text_value": "say tomorrow"
    }
]
```

Note that the action SDK correctly identified "**tomorrow**" as type "`$SchemaOrg_Date`" and bound it to the mydate variable, however, **it did not return the "date_value" element in the return json as specified in the documentation**. I would have expected that "date_value" element to contain a parsed date structure (per the document).

The same is true of numbers although they behave slightly differently. For example, if I use the phrase "**at my action say fifty**", I'll receive these arguments:

```
"arguments": [
    {
        "name": "mynumber",
        "raw_text": "50",
        "text_value": "50"
    },
    {
        "name": "trigger_query",
        "raw_text": "say fifty",
        "text_value": "say fifty"
    }
]
```

Note that the `$SchemaOrg_Number` was recognized and "fifty" was correctly parsed to "50", but the int_value wasn't populated in the argument json per the documentation.

Google is actively parsing these complex types and has documented that they should be returned so I don't want to go to the trouble of parsing them myself. Any thoughts as to if this will be fixed any time soon?

Answer (score 1):

The Actions SDK does not support NLU for actions. You have to use your own NLU. If you don't have your own NLU, we recommend using API.AI.

Comment: I've seen that same answer posted elsewhere, but it's inconsistent with the Google documentation. Can I assume, given your title, that your answer represents an official position from Google? Will the documentation be updated to reflect the actual operation of the API?

It seems like half of the NLP processing is already being done by Google, but the results are simply missing. I'm developing a framework (in Go) and don't want to duplicate functionality that Google might be about to support so any clarification would be really helpful.

Thanks,

Comment: As far as I know the docs are correct. Can you point out where you believe its inconsistent.

Comment: Leon, thanks for the response. See the Arguments section of the reference for the HTTP request

https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/conversation#Inputs

The docs refer to an int_value, bool_value, date_value, time_value, and location_value and says that they should be returned when the appropriate $SchemaOrg_XXXXX value is encountered. They are never populated in the JSON (refer to my question above). 

The types are correct, so Google is doing some NLP, but the actual values are never provided. I need to understand if this is by design.

Comment: Both `raw_text` and `text_value` will be supported going forward, right? Not just `raw_text`?